# 3D model together with deep zoom in WPF

Tags: wpf

Now, I'm trying to think about my topic for senior project. I have an idea about create 3D model which can look around that object and I can zoom it using deep zoom. However, I try to find an information and never see about these concepts together. From these result, I may create 3D model of earth and zoom inside it until I found my country. Is that possible to combine these ?

Best Regards,
C.Porawat

Comment: Your country is *inside* the Earth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you appear to be asking is if you can use the DeepZoom control as a "dynamic texture" to feed the Viewport3D (representing a round earth). This is an interesting thought, but I dont think that will work.

The Viewport3D will tell the deepzoom control to render at a uniform resolution everywhere, and then uses the resulting texture. If you zoom in on Europe, for instance, the deepzoom control will be asked to paint Australia as well, at the same resolution, even though they are on the other side of the earth. In theory the viewport3D could compute the enclosing box of all visible graphic elements, but in the typical scenarios for Viewport3D this will not improve performance in a noticable way, so I doubt they do this. It's not exactly trivial either.

What you can do, is switch over from 3D to 2D at some level of resolution. So you first spin around the earth in 3D (you should be able to do this in WPF), and allow users to zoom in, and when you've zoomed in to "country level", you switch to a deepzoom control that allows you to zoom to street level.

Comment: Thank you so much. Thus, I will decide this to be my senior project

Comment: @Porawat Chimcerdsin: You're welcome. If you feel this post is the answer to your question, you can mark it as the answer by clicking on the green checkmark on the left. This is how the website knows it question does not need an answer anymore. While you're at it, you can go back to your other questions and do the same (assuming you got a useful answer). It even gains you reputation points!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CodeProject sample that uses OpenGL and WPF:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFOpenGL.aspx

OpenGL is cross-platform, so time spent learning this will translate to non-Windows environments as well.

Comment: Is that possible to use viewport3D insted of OpenGL?